# How to reset State in React so the view updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reset a input field on state update. So when my state updates through a function my view would change as well. Below is my code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { song: '',
                   videos: '' }
    this.handleSongInput = this.handleSongInput.bind(this)
}
```

in my render function I do something like this

```
render () {
    return (
            <div>
                <TextField
                  floatingLabelText="Search Songs"
                  value={this.state.value}
                  onChange={this.handleSongInput}
                />
                <br />
                <RaisedButton label="Search" onClick={this.searchSong} />
            </div>
    )
}
```

The handle function for the Input field is below. It is simply setting the state.

```
handleSongInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({ song: e.target.value})
    }
```

Now on button click I have the following function which resets the initial

```
searchSong = () => {
        ...
        this.setState({song:''})
    }
```

Now if I do a console.log I can see that the state has changed. But in my view I can still see that the text field is populated with previous text. [image]

How can I set the value of textfield with current state

Comment: Replace -  this.state.value to this.state.song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a variable name issue:

`value={this.state.value}`

should read:

`value={this.state.song}`